Looking for compatible pulley wheels with shimano RD-1050
I have an old Shimano RD-1050, this exact one and i'm looking for spare pulley wheels. Original G-pulley is marked 'Centeron' and is 8.3mm thick, the other one is unmarked and is 8.9mm. Both have 10 teeth.
I found some universal set with reference Y-56398030 that has same amount of teeth.
I also found BBB Rollerboys 10T, reference BDP-01.
My questions are :

Will it fit?
If not, what would?
is the teeth number actually important?
what is the original part number of the pulley set that was compatible with this model?

Thanks
EDIT: got a reply from BBB customer service. They gave me a table of pulley width. :

and said more intermediate widths could be obtained by mixing the shims. Please note these sizes apply to 10 and 11teeth pulleys. Many thanks to them.


It should fit. a) BBB and other aftermarket pulleys (like the abandoned Tacx ones) are provided with shims for the correct width. You just choose the right ones.
b) The Shimano universal ones should fit straight away if you are fine with the simpler design with bushings.

I am not aware of anything else.

The number off teeth is proportional to the diameter. You cannot fit a pulley wheel that is too different in diameter. The difference of one tooth will likely be fine but check that there is enough space for the chain in the cage.

I have no idea.


A final remark: Centeron pulleys, with some intentional lateral play, are not a thing anymore. You should be fine with a normal pulley wheel from one of the mentioned sets even if it is slightly wider and does not move side to side so much. It is possible to find some more specific replacements, but they can be expensive (like https://bicyclist.cc/product/tranz-x-centeron-g-pulley-jockey-wheels-red/ that also comes with spacers for different widths) or may come from some old stock (various finds on vintage part selling sites or eBay or similar).
